# Как сдублировать кнопку с partial view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть представление, которая использует частичное представление. В этом  частичном представлении есть BeginForm, поля с данными и кнопка submit.

Как можно сделать второй submit на представлении, которое использует это частичное представление и чтобы он также передавал данные с этого частичного представления?

Answer (score 1):

Вложенные BeginForm к сожалению использовать нельзя. Можно использовать javascript и отправить синхронный/асинхронный post-запрос из частичного представления. В этом случае внутренний BeginForm не понадобится. А для всего представления останется один общий submit.

Comment: Я переписал код. Вместо хелпера, я написал обычную форму через html и использовал атрибут form.